# Is directional shadow mapping without projection matrix possible?

Tags: shadow-mapping, projection-matrix

I have found this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786951/omnidirectional-shadow-mapping-with-depth-cubemap?rq=4) where they use a cubemap for pointlight shadow and they don't need to retrieve the faceindex and the projection matrix. This greatly improve the FPS. I was wondering if this method can be applied to directional shadows.

Comment: Transforming a point into directional light space is just three dot products and a vector addition — about as dirt cheap as you can get. It doesn't have the complications of figuring out which side of a cube to sample in the first place, because there's only one side. So this omni light code example sounds like it's solving a problem that just does not exist for directional lights. What specific profiling is telling you that this transformation is the bottleneck in your directional shadow mapping?

Comment: Well globally the deferred lighting pass is my bottle neck. It performs better with the code mentionned because it removes a mul matrix and other lines and it is for 4 dynamic pointlights with shadows.  So as you said this must be the cheaper way to do directional shadows.